# Populate android listview Android

Tags: android, listview, android-listview

My listview below contains only one textview per row.  I need another textview to add a second textview to my row. the problem is i dont know how to populate more than one textview. it there is a second textview txIndex for example. How can i modify my adapter to populate data from two textviews.

```
String[] bible_list_one = getResources().getStringArray(R.array.bible_list_one);
        String[] bible_list_two = getResources().getStringArray(R.array.bible_list_two);

    list.setAdapter(new ArrayAdapter<String>(this,
            android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, bible_list_one));
    list.setOnItemClickListener(this);


    secondlist.setAdapter(new ArrayAdapter<String>(this,
            android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, bible_list_two));
    secondlist.setOnItemClickListener(this);
```

Comment: You should use Custom ListView, so that you can place your widgets like textView, Button any things.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You will have to write your own [CustomArrayAdapter](http://www.mkyong.com/android/android-listview-example/). I hope the tutorial link is helpful.

Answer (score 0):

Check this out: [Android Hive Link](http://www.androidhive.info/2012/02/android-custom-listview-with-image-and-text/)

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
    <RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="100dp"
        android:background="@drawable/listselect"
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        android:padding="5dip" >

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/txtViewNameDAR"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="Name : "
            android:textColor="#040404"
            android:textSize="15sp"
            android:textStyle="bold"
            android:typeface="sans" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/txtViewVisitedCityDAR"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
            android:layout_centerVertical="true"
            android:text="Type : "
            android:textColor="#343434"
            android:textSize="13sp" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/textViewTypeDAR"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
            android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
            android:text="Visited City : "
            android:textColor="#343434"
            android:textSize="13sp" />

    </RelativeLayout>
```

Change the IDs and colors to your needs.

This is an independent XML file.
Use it like below :

```
list.setAdapter(new ArrayAdapter<String>(this,
            "R.Layout.ABOVE_XML_FILENAME, bible_list_one));
```

Then, In getView

```
TextView text = (TextView) row.findViewById(" Your Desired textViewID");
text.setText(" ");
```

Hope you get some idea